# calculating if date falls within a given range

Tags: ms-access

I'm working with MS Access 2010.

I have a table of projects and each project has a STARTDATE, ENDDATE, and a True/False field for ACTIVE.  Active is true if today's date is within Start and End dates - and I want it to be automatically checked or unchecked.

How do I write this event in VBA??

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why your table needs a field for Active.  Based on your description it will be True if the current date is within that date range, and False otherwise.  So this can be accomplished from a query.

```
SELECT
    STARTDATE,
    ENDDATE,
    IIf(Date() >= STARTDATE AND Date() <= ENDDATE,
        True, False) AS Active
FROM YourTable;
```

**Edit**:  However, if you do want to store Active as a field in your table, you can include that IIf() expression in an UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourTable.Active =  IIf(Date() >= [STARTDATE]
    AND Date() <= [ENDDATE],
    True, False);
```

Comment: I have never quite understood why a programmer would wrap a Boolean value in an IIf() in order to convert it to... a Boolean value.

Comment: `IIf()` guarantees we always get a Boolean even when `STARTDATE` and/or `ENDATE` is Null.  That may not be so important for the `SELECT`, but is critical for the `UPDATE` if he chose to go that way.    Access will not accept Null in a Yes/No field.

Comment: Then use `Nz()` instead of depending on the side effects another function. This clearly expresses your intent of Null handling instead of Boolean conversion. Otherwise you are tricking other programmers who see the code.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, **if the active status of a row is wholly dependent on the active dates then the table should not have an Active column**.

So first, remove the Active column in your table. Create a new query:

```
SELECT
   *,
   Now() >= StartDate And Now() < EndDate AS Active
FROM YourTable
```

Now use this query in every place that you currently use the table. If you have performance problems, replace `WHERE Active = True` with the above condition `WHERE Now() >= StartDate And Now() < EndDate`.

Some notes:

Defining a VB Function is not a good idea as this creates a bunch of complexity that will definitely hurt performance for no really compelling reason.

Trying to keep the table in sync is not a good idea because you will eventually run into a race condition, a failed update, or an inconsistency that pulls wrong data.

If you insist on keeping the column and trying to synchronize the values, then you'll put some code on the AfterUpdate events of the startdate and enddate text boxes, as well as Form Current, to set the active flag based on the current time. This would also require some frequent job that updated all the rows in the table to Active or Inactive based on the current time progressing. If you're lucky you might not have too many problems with this scheme.

Answer (score 0):

In vba you can use Date.Now to get the current date.
If you are building a query you can simple put as a where clause:

```
WHERE Now between STARTDATE and ENDDATE
```

If you are doing this in a vba code, for instance in a loop, you can have something like

```
if Date.Now > STARTDATE and Date.Now < ENDDATE Then
 ...
end if
```

Comment: You do know that BETWEEN vs. > < are not the same? Which is correct?

Comment: @ErikE yes! I've been ranting about this for 10 years. 2002: http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/should-i-use-between-in-my-database-queries.html 2009: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Comment: Between in inclusive of both values when < and > are not, obviously.  So it is a question of how you want to state your query.